# Get Values from Key in Nested Json code with Python

Tags: python

Hi i try to get 2 values from a Json code with Python, first the Root String and Second the value from key Text.

Have Tired this but can not get value by key because it is not a dict.
My Json gets converted to a list object, i am new to Python so hope for some help.

```
import json

def main():
    json_val = '["\u2500\u2500!  ",[[[["kotchi",{"reading":"\u3053\u3063\u3061","text":"\u3053\u3063\u3061","kana":"\u3053\u3063\u3061","score":40,"seq":1004500,"gloss":[{"pos":"[pn]","gloss":"this way; this direction","info":"direction close to the speaker or towards the speaker"},{"pos":"[pn]","gloss":"here","info":"place close to the speaker or where the speaker is"},{"pos":"[pn]","gloss":"this (one)","info":"something physically close to the speaker"},{"pos":"[pn]","gloss":"I; me; we; us"}],"conj":[]},[]],["da",{"reading":"\u3060","text":"\u3060","kana":"\u3060","score":16,"seq":2089020,"gloss":[{"pos":"[cop,cop-da]","gloss":"be; is","info":"plain copula"},{"pos":"[aux-v]","gloss":"did; (have) done","info":"\u305F after certain verb forms; indicates past or completed action"},{"pos":"[aux-v]","gloss":"please; do","info":"indicates light imperative"}],"conj":[]},[]]],66]],"! "]'
    
    resp  = json.loads(json_val)
            
    for item in resp:
        if isinstance(item, (str)):
            print(item)
        if not isinstance(item, (str)):
            for text_out in item[0][0]:
                print(text_out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here the Json Code i try to get values from.

```
[
  "──!  ",
  [
    [
      [
        [
          "kotchi",
          {
            "reading": "こっち",
            "text": "こっち",
            "kana": "こっち",
            "score": 40,
            "seq": 1004500,
            "gloss": [
              {
                "pos": "[pn]",
                "gloss": "this way; this direction",
                "info": "direction close to the speaker or towards the speaker"
              },
              {
                "pos": "[pn]",
                "gloss": "here",
                "info": "place close to the speaker or where the speaker is"
              },
              {
                "pos": "[pn]",
                "gloss": "this (one)",
                "info": "something physically close to the speaker"
              },
              {
                "pos": "[pn]",
                "gloss": "I; me; we; us"
              }
            ],
            "conj": []
          },
          []
        ],
        [
          "da",
          {
            "reading": "だ",
            "text": "だ",
            "kana": "だ",
            "score": 16,
            "seq": 2089020,
            "gloss": [
              {
                "pos": "[cop,cop-da]",
                "gloss": "be; is",
                "info": "plain copula"
              },
              {
                "pos": "[aux-v]",
                "gloss": "did; (have) done",
                "info": "た after certain verb forms; indicates past or completed action"
              },
              {
                "pos": "[aux-v]",
                "gloss": "please; do",
                "info": "indicates light imperative"
              }
            ],
            "conj": []
          },
          []
        ]
      ],
      66
    ]
  ],
  "! "
]
```

Comment: Which element in the JSON are you trying to access?